# How to use session to be alive between http and https laravel 5.1

Tags: http, session, ssl, https, laravel-5.1

We recently bought an SSL from goDaddy domain and the site successfully used that SSL to amazon ec2. Though we will only use the https on a specific url like the billing (eg. **https://www.ourdomain.com/billing**) and the rest of the sites will still use the "**HTTP**"

My question is, is it possible for the session to be alive when switching to different protocol or http/https?

I found this link which should be the solution but when I tried adding the

```
'secure'    => true,
'http_only' => true,
```

it still didn't work.

Also when I tried logging-in using just the **HTTP**, i am unable to login. It seems the app is not functioning.

Sorry, this is my first time using SSL on a site. Any pointers is much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: secure and http-only are options for cookies. http-only means cookie would not accesable in browser javascript, secure means cookie would pass througth secure protocol (https) only. so, if you want to use http, secure option should be equal false

Comment: it worked!. haha. so i read it wrong. :(.